# Prove that $V$-valued two-player games of perfect information have an optimal strategy and payoff

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, combinatorial-game-theory

## Problem

> **Definition**. Let $V$ be a non-empty set of real numbers. The class VG of $V$-*valued two-person deterministic games of perfect information* is defined recursively as follows:
>
> **Base case**. A value $v\in V$ is a VG knows as a *payoff*.
>
> **Constructor case**: If $G$ is a non-empty set of VG's, then $G$ is a VG. Each game $M\in G$ is called a possible *first move* of $G$.
>
> A *strategy* for a player is a function *s* from games to games with the property that $s(G)\in G$ for all games $G$. Given which player has the first move, a pair of strategies for the two players determines exactly which moves the players will choose. So, the strategies determine a unique play of the game and a unique payoff.
>
> The *max-player* wants a strategy that guarantees as high a payoff as possible, and the *min-player* wants a strategy that guarantees as low a payoff as possible.
>
> The Fundamental Theorem for deterministic games of perfect information says that in any game, each player has an optimal strategy, and these strategies lead to the same payoff. More precisely,
>
> **Theorem** (Fundamental Theorem for VG's). Let $V$ be a finite set of real numbers and $G$ be a $V$-valued VG. Then there is a value $v\in V$, called a *max-value* $\text{max}_G$ for $G$, such that if the max-player moves first,
>
> - the max-player has a strategy that will finish with a payoff of at least $\text{max}_G$, no matter what strategy the min-player uses, and
> - the min-player has a strategy that will finish with a payoff of at most $\text{max}_G$, no matter what strategy the max-player uses.
>
> Prove the Fundamental Theorem for VG's.

Can anybody please verify the following solution attempt?

## Solution attempt

Proof by structural induction.

**Induction hypothesis**: $P(G)$ := There is a value $v\in V$, called max-value $\text{max}_G$ for $G$, such that, if the max-player moves first,

- the max-player has a strategy that will finish with a payoff of at least $\text{max}_G$, no matter what strategy the min-player uses
- the min-player has a strategy that will finish with a payoff of at most $\text{max}_G$, no matter what strategy the max-player uses

**Base case** ($G = v \in V$): If the max-player is the first player, the strategy is to do nothing and finish with payoff $\text{max}_G = v$.

**Constructor case** ($G = \left\{M\text{ | }M \in \text{VG}\right\}$): Assume that $P(M)$ is true for all $M\in G$.

By cases:

1. The max-player has the next move in $G$. For any $M\in G$ that the max-player picks, the min-player will be the first player in $M$. Suppose the max-player picks a move $M$.

   1.1. If $M = v \in V$, the max-player's strategy is to do nothing and finish with payoff $\text{max}_G = v$.

   1.2. If $M = \left\{N | N \in \text{VG}\right\}$, then suppose the min-player picks some $N \in M$. By the induction hypothesis, since the max-player moves first in $N$, then there is a $\text{max}_N$ such that:

   - the max-player will have a strategy that ends with payoff at least $\text{max}_N$, and
   - the min-player will have a strategy that ends with payoff at most $\text{max}_N$.

   So, for $G$, the strategy for either max-player or min-player is: first, the max-player makes any available move, then the min-player makes any available move, then both can carry out their strategies for the remaining moves, and the payoff will be $\text{max}_G = \text{max}_N$.
2. The min-player has the next move in $G$. For any $M\in G$ that the min-player chooses, the max-player will be the first player in $M$.

   By the induction hypothesis, for any $M$ that the min-player chooses, there is a $\text{max}_M$ such that:

   - the max-player will have an optimal strategy that ends with payoff at least $\text{max}_M$, and
   - the min-player will have an optimal strategy that ends with payoff at most $\text{max}_M$.

   So, for $G$, $\text{max}_G$ = $\text{max}_M$.

Therefore, by structural induction, $P(G)$ is true for all $G$ in $\textrm{VG}$.